# How can I get the <a> element to fill the <li> in this table so that each cell is a link and not just the text?

Tags: html, css

Hey there can anyone help me out. I am creating a table as a submenu on a website and I am unable to figure out how I can get the < a > element to fill the < li > in this table so that each cell is a link and not just the text

```
<ul>
   <li class="list-heading">Important Services</li>
   <li class="red-elem"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li class="red-elem"><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li class="red-elem"><a href="#">Our Work</a></li>
   <li class="red-elem"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
   <li class="red-elem"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<style>
.list-heading {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 150%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ac0303;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px black solid;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.red-elem {
  font-family:Roboto;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 150%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ac0303;
  border-bottom: 1px black solid;
}
.red-elem a {
  color: white;
}
</style>
```

Comment: add display: block; on your a tag, I posted an answer check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add display block to your `a tag` see the updated code below

```html
<ul>
   <li class="list-heading">Important Services</li>
   <li class="red-elem"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li class="red-elem"><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li class="red-elem"><a href="#">Our Work</a></li>
   <li class="red-elem"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
   <li class="red-elem"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<style>
.list-heading {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 150%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ac0303;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px black solid;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.red-elem {
  font-family:Roboto;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 150%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ac0303;
  border-bottom: 1px black solid;
}
.red-elem a {
  color: white;
  display:block;
}
</style>
```

Comment: No problem glad it helped :) You can accept the answer if it work

Comment: I will for sure, I am just new to StackOverflow, so I have to wait 11 min before accepting it due to the StackOverflow policy -_-

Comment: There we go, sorry about the delay! Thanks again :) !

Answer (score 0):

```
.red-elem a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

... and remove the padding on `li`, and add to `<a>` as per the next answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove padding from the `.red-elem` and add it to the links instead

```css
.list-heading {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 150%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ac0303;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 1px black solid;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.red-elem {
  font-family:Roboto;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 150%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: #ac0303;
  border-bottom: 1px black solid;
}
.red-elem a {
  color: white;
  display:block;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li class="list-heading">Important Services</li>
   <li class="red-elem"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li class="red-elem"><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li class="red-elem"><a href="#">Our Work</a></li>
   <li class="red-elem"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
   <li class="red-elem"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```